# Generating multiple CSV files on hourly basis in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a python module called HourlyCsvGeneration.py. I have some data which is being generated on hourly basis which is is sample.txt. Here is the sample of the data in the sample.txt:-

```
2014-07-24 15:00:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:01:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:02:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:15:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:16:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:17:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:30:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:31:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:32:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:45:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:46:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:47:00,1,1,1,1,1001
```

As you can see there are 4 intervals 00-15, 15-30, 30,45 and 45-59 and the next hour starts and so on. I am writing the code that would read the data in this txt file and generating 4 CSV files for every hour in a day. So analysing the above data the 4 CSV files should be generated should have naming convention like 2014-07-24 15:00.csv containing the data between 15:00 and 15:15, 2014-07-24 15:15.csv containing the data between 15:15 and 15:30 and so on for every hour. The python code must handle all this.

Here is my current code snippet:-

```
import csv
def connection():
    fo = open("sample.txt", "r")
    data = fo.readlines()
    header = ['tech', 'band', 'region', 'market', 'code']
    for line in data:
            line = line.strip("\n")
            line = line.split(",")
            time = line[0]
            lines = [x for x in time.split(':') if x]
            i = len(lines)
            if i == 0:
                    continue
            else:
                    hour, minute, sec = lines[0], lines[1], lines[2]
                    minute = int(minute)
                    if minute >= 0 and minute < 15:
                            print hour, minute
                            print line[1:]
                    elif minute >= 15 and minute < 30:
                            print hour, minute
                            print line[1:]
                    elif minute >= 30 and minute < 45:
                            print hour, minute
                            print line[1:]
                    elif minute >=45 and minute < 59:
                            print hour, minute
                            print line[1:]
connection()
```

[1:] gives the right data for each interval and I am kind off stuck in generating CSV files and writing the data. So instead of printing [1:], I want this to be get written in the csv file of that interval with the appropriate naming convention as explained in the above description.

Expected output:-

```
2014-07-24 15:00.csv must contain
1,1,1,1,1001
1,1,1,1,1001
1,1,1,1,1001

2014-07-24 15:15.csv must contain
1,1,1,1,1001
1,1,1,1,1001
1,1,1,1,1001
```

and so on for 15.30.csv and 15.45.csv. Keeping in mind this is just a small chunk of data. The actual data is for every hour of the data. Meaning generating 4 csv files for each hour that is 24*4 files for one day. So how can I make my code more robust and efficient?

Any help?Thanks

Comment: Considered https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html ?

I mean you could use the CSV reader in the csv module to parse it. Instead of doing it yourself using split and strip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a job for `itertools.groupby`, if the timestamps are strictly increasing in value:

```
from datetime import datetime as DateTime
from itertools import imap, groupby
from operator import itemgetter


get_first = itemgetter(0)
get_second = itemgetter(1)


def process_line(line):
    timestamp_string, _, values = line.partition(',')
    timestamp = DateTime.strptime(timestamp_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return (
        timestamp.replace(minute=timestamp.minute // 15 * 15, second=0),
        values
    )


def main():
    with open('sample.txt', 'r') as lines:
        for date, group in groupby(imap(process_line, lines), get_first):
            with open('{0:%Y-%m-%d %H_%M}.csv'.format(date), 'w') as out_file:
                out_file.writelines(imap(get_second, group))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not trivial, because if you try to open all the output files at once, then you will run out of file descriptors and crash. So what you want to do is open a file in append mode, write one line, then close the file. This isn't a horribly efficient operation, so I wouldn't worry about efficiency yet.

```
outfile = open("2014-07-24 15:00.csv","a")
outfile.write("csv, line, data\n")
outfile.close()
```

Comment: The main thing that I am looking for is generating the csv files with the appropriate naming convention for each interval for every hour from the code's point of view. Can u help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some ways that might help

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

def get_higher_minute(minute_of_day):
    return (((minute_of_day/ 15) + 1 ) % 4) * 15

def connection():
    import csv
    with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            dateObject = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            minute_of_day = dateObject.minute
            higher_minute = get_higher_minute(minute_of_day)
            newdate = dateObject.replace(minute = higher_minute)
            file_name_of_new_csv = "%s.csv" % dateObject.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
            new_csv_writer = csv.writer(file_name_of_new_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            new_csv_writer.writerow(row[0:])
            new_csv_writer.close()            

def main():
    connection()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Hope it helps

Sorry. left new_csv_writer open.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Hitesh. I will try it and get back to you in a bit:)

Comment: I am not sure of your data collection timelines, If you are getting one file per hour. it would be easier to sort by time and then process them in chunks. That would lessen the number of file descriptors opening and closing shaving off some time

Comment: Actually I want 4 files per hour instead of one. The reason being I have to write another script and do some processing on those 4 different files of that hour.

Comment: Can you please edit the answer editing the code you forgot to insert?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "updated.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "updated.py", line 22, in main
    connection()
  File "updated.py", line 17, in connection
    new_csv_writer = csv.writer(open(file_name_of_new_csv), delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2014-07-24 15:00.csv'

Comment: Hi Hitesh, I sorted the error but it is not giving me the expected output. Instead of creating 4 csv files of intervals 0-15, 15-30, 30-45 and 45-59, it is creating  csv files for each minute

Comment: newdate = dateObject.replace(minute = higher_minute)
ValueError: minute must be in 0..59

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using pandas for this.  It takes care of a whole bunch of the dirty work for you.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('DummyText.txt',sep=',',index_col=0,parse_dates=True,header=None)
fname = (str(pd.datetime(2014,7,24,15,0))+'.csv').replace(':','-')
df[pd.datetime(2014,7,24,15,0):pd.datetime(2014,7,24,15,15)].to_csv(fname,header=None)
```

I took the `:` out of the filename.  It didn't seem to like that.
All you need to do with the above is setup some loops to cycle through the dates and times.

Comment: I would highly appreciate if you help a little more with the code.

Comment: pandas definitely going to do most of heavy lifting for you,  between pd.read_table and to_csv methods you got almost everything you need. Documentation at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Comment: @sam could you clarify a bit what you need help with exactly?  Do you need explanation of the code itself or what to do with it next?  As is that little snippet will read in the file that you gave us, pull out data from the first 15 mins and write it to a csv in the same format with a filename as requested.